# Composition of weakly convergent sequence with nonlinear function

Tags: functional-analysis

There are some similar questions to this one, see for instance ([Weak Convergence of Composition in Sobolev Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214289/weak-convergence-of-composition-in-sobolev-space?rq=1)) and ([Composition of a weakly convergent sequence with a nonlinear function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685967/composition-of-a-weakly-convergent-sequence-with-a-nonlinear-function)), but they are about the specific case of Sobolev spaces. I was wondering if similar things can be said in the case when we have a function $F: U \to V$ between Banach spaces.

If $F$ is linear and bounded, it is possible to prove that given a weakly convergent sequence $v_k$, $F(v_k)$ will also converge weakly in $V$, ([Bounded operator on weakly convergent sequence maps to weakly convergent sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3024850/bounded-operator-on-weakly-convergent-sequence-maps-to-weakly-convergent-sequenc)).

I am wondering what can be said if $F$ is not linear? Will a weakly convergent sequence map to a weakly convergent sequence if $F$ is bounded and continuous? Locally Lipschitz? Or what if $F$ is only continuous. Are more assumptions needed?

Comment: What is the precise question?

Comment: sorry, clarified my question

Comment: Definitely more assumptions are needed; see for example pg.7 of [these notes](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4380/v06/Weakconvergence.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to formulate a nice general theorem. The main obstruction is the following $L^p$ fact (Proposition 2.10 of [these lecture notes](https://www-m7.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M7/Analysis/PDE2-10/July_25.pdf), for example). Here $p\in [1, \infty)$.

**Proposition**. Suppose $\psi\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is such that $\psi\circ f_n$ converges weakly in $L^p(0, 1)$ to $\psi\circ f$ for each $f_n\in L^p(0, 1)$ that converges weakly to $f$. Then $\psi$ is affine.

Using this, you can construct nonlinear operators of $L^p(0, 1)$ into itself with any prescribed degree of smoothness and that are not weakly continuous.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! Follow up-question, given a function that maps a Banach space to Banach spaces, if I understand your answer, I cannot say that F(u_k) will be bounded if u_k is weakly convergent (and bounded), even if F is bounded?

Comment: You should explain what "bounded" means, for a nonlinear function $F$. It can mean that it maps bounded sets to bounded sets, or that its range is bounded. In any case, the answer to your question is negative; if $u_k$ is bounded, then $F$ maps it to a bounded sequence. Where did I say the opposite?

Comment: Oh, you didn't, sorry for being unclear. If I mean bounded in the sense that $\| Fu \|_U \leq \|u\|_V$. This should then mean that if we are working with Hilbert spaces, we should get weak convergence?

Comment: Ok. Yeah. So, there is an important point that is slipping between our hands here. I am talking about $F$ being *weakly continuous*, which for me means that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ implies $F(f_n) \rightharpoonup F(f)$. This is hard stuff and typically if $F$ satisfies this, then it is a trivial operator (see the theorem above). You are asking for a weaker property, namely that if $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ then $F(f_n)\rightharpoonup g$ **up to a subsequence** and **for some** $g$. Now, this is definitely true if the target space is reflexive, for example if it is Hilbert, as you point out.

Comment: Okay, so in general, if I want this property (that f(v_n) is to converge to F(v_0)) I have to assume that the function is weakly continuous which means that it will be affine? Does this hold for any Banach space or just $L^p$? I take it that it woud hold for at least Bochner spaces (these are the ones I am interested in) $L^2([a,b],V)$. Do you have a reference to recommend?

Comment: No, I don't. The "affine" thing is a property of $L^p$. Maybe it holds for $L^2(a, b, V)$, too. No idea there. And I don't have a clue so as to where to look for that, either. You may try Math Overflow.